# Google Maps assign a php pop-up window on clicking a marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Assume I have put a marker at a specific location on the Map.
I want the program to open a pop-up window called bla.php when the user click on this marker.

This is what I already done to put the marker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxVucBtLP4XefoM4syoigBgXntwkVGxv8&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(48, 2),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

var position = new google.maps.LatLng(48,2);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map
});

marker.setTitle("pv-unit");  
}

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
```

I tried it, the whole map is not loading

Comment: How do you usually open a pop-up window?

Comment: @geocodezip  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   // Popup window code
    function newPopup(url) {
 popupWindow = window.open(
  url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=700,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
  }
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('pop-up.html');">Open pop-up</a>

Comment: Use that code (which isn't very readable in a comment) in the click listener for the marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need an event listener for your marker.  Then within that, whatever code you want for opening a popup, e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.open('blah.php','name','height=200,width=150');
});
```

Comment: check out the new code in the question with your part added to it, maybe there's something wrong somewhere else